# Node Socket io emit from client to server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

New to socket io and node generally.

I am trying to fire a socket.emit event on a button click from the client.

On button click my console.log works fine, however the socket.emit('chart', 'foo') does not. 
Moving the socket.emit outside of the function works just fine.

Server

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    client.on('chart', function(clientConfig){
    console.log('Chart settings have been updated!' + clientConfig);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');

socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function () {
        socket.emit('chart', 'foo' );
        console.log('button works');
    });
});
```

Comment: There's nothing generically wrong here so it's probably some error somewhere in code you don't show or a timing issue.  If you put a `console.log()` inside the server connection event, do you see the client connect?  Do you see any client-side errors in the log?  You need to establish whether the client connects to the server or not.

Comment: I think  we need to see more code and more debugging about whether you are actually getting a connection between client and server or not.

Comment: I agree with the above. There's nothing wrong with the code as far as I can see, but you'll need to drill down and do some more debugging/logging for anyone here to be able to help, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

try to remove localhost from `io()` like this `const socket = io();`

Btw, `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` do you pass correct server object there ? is it working on the backend ?

Comment: the answer is this ` const socket = io();` but in order to work in needs a working node js web socket server which we don't know if it works because you havent posted any code

Comment: If localhost is the correct server and port 80 is the correct port, then `var socket = io('http://localhost');` will work JUST fine too.  So, you are making a wild guess with no explained logic behind it.

Comment: okey :) in my opinion the error is there or your `server` is not correct.  a simple copy-paste from here should work https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ 
if you post more code it will be easier to find the actual problem

Comment: sorry @jfriend00 , for a moment i thought you were asked the question